# Is the inverse of a continuous embedding between subspaces of $\ell^1$ and $\ell^2$ a continuous linear operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $X \subset \ell^1$ be a infinite linearly independent subset of $\ell^1$ over the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$

Let $V= \operatorname{span}(X)$

Let $T : (V,\left\| \cdot \right\|_{\ell^1}) \to (V,\left\| \cdot \right\|_{\ell^2})$ be the continuous embedding so $\forall v \in V : T(v)=v$

I would like to know if is it true that the $T^{-1}$ inverse of $T$ is a continuous linear operator.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If X=$l^1$ ,the inverse of T is not continuous .For otherwise the image would be closed and since it is dense would give that $l^1$=$l^2$ .

Comment: thanks @StuartMN for your answer